# Edit permssion only for survey but not for page

Tags: permissions, wiki, survey-list

I  have  nearly  100 sub sites  which contain wikis & survey .I have given edit item level permission so that the user is able to update/edit survey & wiki but at the same time user is able to edit page but I would like to restrict user for editing page .

I don’t want break inheritance and assign permission for each survey &  wiki separately but want permission group applicable to all (restricting page edit)

If you have experienced  same scenario please extend your support.

Answer (score 1):

You need to separate the wikis and the surveys. Wiki pages are part of editing rights, and you can't edit surveys without editing the wiki pages. Alternatively, you can remove the "Edit Items" permission level, although users will not be able to edit the surveys they created.